# Manipulate scale of axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and using it to plot a histogram. The data looks like:

```
y_axis=[82.34,0.009,0.1,1.45,0.01]
x_axis=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
```

The problem is when I plot it, y-axis values like 0.009 and 0.01 don't appear in graph and they appear to be 0. So is there a way to manipulate axis scale for a specific range. Like the ticks difference between 0 and 1 is factor of 0.1, but for range above 1, distance between ticks is 10.

Basically I am looking for a way to manipulate scale of axis such that you have two different scale for a specific axis.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want a logarithmic scale. There are several ways to do this. One way is to use [`plt.semilogy`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_data = [82.34,0.009,0.1,1.45,0.01]
x_data = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]

plt.semilogy(x_data,y_data,'bo-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively you could make your plot with `plt.plot`, and then set the `yaxis` to a log scale later with [`Axes.set_yscale('log')`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale):

```
plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'bo-')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
```